# Rename files with batch commands - routine

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I have some files from "file_1" to "file_50" I want to rename some of the files from "file_1" to "file_9" in "file_01" to "file_09" (so if the number is less than 10 I would like to add a 0).Unfortunately, I am not expert with batch How could I do with batch commands?

I guess I should do something like

```
@echo off
for (don't know what to put) do (
ren
)
popd
```

But I do not know how to conclude
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your filenames match your example, then all you need is:

> ren file_?.* file_0?.*

The ? is a wildcard for a single character.  Therefore file_?1.* requires a *single* character to be present before the . (dot).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. How can I implement in a for cycle? This


        set MYDIR=C:\something
        for /F %%x in ('dir /B/D %MYDIR%') do (ren file_?.* to file_0?.*)

would work?

Comment: oops, i added "to" for some reason, took that out.  As for looping, i dont use batch scripting that much, as i prefer powershell.  Hmm...

Comment: @Klapaucius.... Give `FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%x in ('DIR /B /A-D "%MYDIR%\file_?.*"') DO REN "%MYDIR%\%%~x" "file_0?.*"` a shot. You will obviously need to set the `MYDIR` variable accordingly and accurately. Thank you for shopping at Walmart!

Comment: [Mr. @Keltari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari)... when are you going to upgrade to a [Playstation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation)... Come to Walmart and shop 'til you drop BIG homie!! Be sure you "say it" and "not spray it" too.

Comment: Ok thanks, but If I want to automatize it (I just want to click on the file and have it done) I have read I need to use `%cd%` but if I run `FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%x in ('DIR /B /A-D "%cd%\file_?.*"') DO REN "%cd%\%%~x" "file_0?.*"` I get an error

Comment: The error is that a duplicate exists; it reneames them in file_0: it does not recognize the ?